# help with mysql AES_ENCRYPT

Tags: php, mysql

I have prepared a query but it keeps throwing errors. Here is my query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO encryption_tests (values) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT('pass', 'password'))";
```

I have successfully connected to the server and selected a database. Here is the `mysql_error()`:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'values) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT('pass', 'password'))' at line 1

Can anybody see anything I'm not seeing? Thanks for your help and if you have any questions, do ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`values` is a MySQL reserved word. You need to escape it with backticks like so:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `encryption_tests` (`values`) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT('pass', 'password'))";
```

Although my personal preference is to write queries this way as I find them much easier to read:

```
INSERT INTO `encryption_tests`
SET `values` = AES_ENCRYPT('pass', 'password')
```